# How to get mySQL Database max. capacity in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to read the max. capacity of a MySQL database in PHP?

I have made a class to secure the databases from gettin overflowed. It works great, only problem is i cant get the max DB size (of each db). I have to set it manually like this:

```
class StorageSecurity
{
    private static $MAX_DB_SIZE = 100; //MB

    private $_db_host;  //Database Host
    private $_db_user;  //Database Username
    private $_db_pass;  //Database Userpass

    public function  __construct(Database $_db)
    {
      try
      {
        $this->_errors  = Array();
        $this->_db_host = $_db->getDBHost();
        $this->_db_user = $_db->getDBUser();
        $this->_db_pass = $_db->getDBPass();

        $this->setMaxDBCapacity(self::$MAX_DB_SIZE);

        $db_conn = mysql_pconnect($this->_db_host, $this->_db_user,
                                  $this->_db_pass);

        if (!$db_conn) throw new Exception("Server Connection Failed.");

      } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by max capacity?  Does it include the size of the log files (for InnoDB)?  Is it based on the amount of space left on your disk?

Comment: max db size , i think, there is no another description for it.

Comment: I am using "SHOW TABLE STATUS" to get current size of the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "max db size" you mean "maximum size of the associated db files such that it will not exceed the available storage space", it obviously depends on whether or not other applications can write to the same filesystem partition as the database.

In MySQL, you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` to calculate the estimate (from the storage engine, e.g. InnoDB) of the amount of disk space **used** by a database (`test` in this case):

```
SELECT SUM(DATA_LENGTH) + SUM(INDEX_LENGTH) AS usage_estimate 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema = 'test';
```

You can also select the **MySQL** limit (but not the **filesystem** limit) per table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, MAX_DATA_LENGTH 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema = 'test';
```

You could then compare this to some configurable value in your code that you considered the "safe" size for each database (keeping in mind that log files, etc. will add to the overall "size" of the database on disk).

More information about INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html

Comment: well, let me try. I'll answer back soon

Comment: @Vural That was my point.  There are many factors that determine "max db capacity" (filesystem limitations on file size, total available disk on the partition, etc.) that the best thing to do is to analyze your application's use of the database to determine a reasonable maximum size for your application and set it in software.  You can then use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to compare actual usage to your maximum.